# Arreglos Dinamicos - No Muestra Valores ingresados

Tags: c++, array, matriz

Estoy aprendiendo a dominar los arreglos dinámicos

Mi código no tiene ningún error, pero no muestra los valores ingresados en la matriz

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
//Implementacion de arreglos bidimensionales Dinámicos
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int **puntero_matriz;
    int filas, columnas;

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de Filas: ";
    cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de columnas: "; 
    cin>>columnas;

    // reservar memoria para la matriz dinámica
    puntero_matriz = new int*[filas]; //reservando memoria para filas
    for(int i = 0; i<filas ; i++){
        puntero_matriz[i] = new int[columnas]; //reservando memoria para columnas
    }

    cout<<"\nIntroduciendo numeros:\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < filas ; i ++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j< columnas ; j ++){
            cout<<"Ingrese el valor de ["<<i<<"] ["<<j<<"] = ";
            cin>>*(*(puntero_matriz+i)+j);
        }
    }

    cout<<"\nImprimiendo la matriz ingresada:\n";
    for (int i ; i < filas ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < columnas ; j++){
            cout<<*(*(puntero_matriz+i)+j)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    //liberando espacio en memoria
    for (int i = 0 ; i< filas ; i ++ ){
        delete[] puntero_matriz[i];
    }
    delete[] puntero_matriz;
}
```

En tiempo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa queda allí sin mostrarme los valores introducidos, me gustaría saber ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: A mi me funciona perfectamente, ingresé una matriz de 2x2 con los valores 1,2,3,4. Y los imprime en la forma de la matriz. También lo proble [acá](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) y funciona.

Comment: @FranAcuna Si, ya veo, creo que debe ser algún problema con mi pc, o el compilador que estoy utilizando en mi pc, de cualquier forma gracias, ahora veo que si estaba bien el programa que hice.